# cannot open include file :'omniORB4' in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I have developed a application using QT on linux and it works fine. Now I ported the application to windows and I am getting issues with the include path in the .pro file of the project. This is my .pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-12-08T09:19:31
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui


greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets




TARGET = FirstProject
TEMPLATE = app
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        firstscreen.cpp \
        secondscreen.cpp \
        thirdscreen.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:\Users\user_name\tango\ \
               C:\Users\user_name\omniORB4\ \
               C:\Users\user_name\omnithread.h





HEADERS  += firstscreen.h \
            C:\Users\user_name\tango\ \
            C:\Users\user_name\omniORB4\ \
            C:\Users\user_name\omnithread.h \
            secondscreen.h \
            thirdscreen.h


LIBS += -L -lomnithread \
        -L -lomniORB4 \
        -L -ltango


FORMS    += firstscreen.ui \
            secondscreen.ui \
            thirdscreen.ui
```

When I build the project it gives me the following error:

```
C:\tango\idl\tango.h:28: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'omniORB4/CORBA.h': No such file or directory
```

When I check in the tango.h file there is a include statement "#include " which is giving me this error. But when I change the include statement to the following it works.

```
#include <C:\Users\user_name\omniORB4/CORBA.h>
```

Could you let me know what is causing this problem. I already have the path specified in the .pro file so it should work without me specifying the entire path in the include statement.

Comment: You do not have `C:\Users\user_name` in your include paths. So it will not find `omniORB4/CORBA.h`. That is unless CORBA.h is in the folder `C:/Users/user_name/omniORB4/omniORB4/CORBA.h`

Comment: @drescherjm I added c:/Users/user_name/omniORB4 in my include path.Wouldnt that be enought?Should i add c:/Users/user_name in the include path separately for it to work?

Comment: ***I added c:/Users/user_name/omniORB4 in my include path.Wouldnt that be enought?*** No that does not help since the path is not `C:/Users/user_name/omniORB4/omniORB4/CORBA.h`. If the original include was `#include <CORBA.h>` you would have been fine with `C:\Users\user_name\omniORB4` in your path however from the error message it appears that it had the folder. `#include <omniORB4/CORBA.h>`

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for the solution.It worked.I am getting a new error saying "cannot open include file "w32win.h". Any idea what would be the reason for it?

Comment: I am not familiar with `w32win.h` it must be part of the libraries that you are using. Figure out what path that this file is in and make sure you update your include paths to solve this.